# Double click event command not always executed

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm quite new to WPF and C#. I'm trying to catch a double click event in an user control and handle it through an ICommand.

Here is how i'm trying to do that:

User Control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.View.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.View"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
         xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
         DataContext="{Binding MyViewModelClass, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
         >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
        <ContentControl>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding DataContext.HandleDoubleClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12" >

                <TextBlock Text="Data: "><Run FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding data}"/></TextBlock>

        </WrapPanel>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{DynamicResource ColorPanel2}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="0"  BorderThickness="0 0 0 1">
        <WrapPanel Margin="12" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18"
                       Text="some text: ">
            </TextBlock>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Border>

    <ListView Grid.Row="1" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.listElement, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
            />

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And i placed the command to handle the event in the ViewModel class:

```
ICommand _HandleDoubleClickCommand;
public ICommand HandleDoubleClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_HandleDoubleClickCommand == null)
        {
            _HandleDoubleClickCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(ExecuteHandleDoubleClickCommand, CanExecuteHandleDoubleClickCommand);
        }
        return _HandleDoubleClickCommand;
    }
}

private bool CanExecuteHandleDoubleClickCommand(object arg)
{
    return true;
}

private void ExecuteHandleDoubleClickCommand(object obj)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("HandleDoubleClickCommand");
}
```

So, basically i have a list of elements and i want to handle the double click event on is.
The behavior i see is that sometimes the HandleDoubleClickCommand gets executed, sometimes it's not. I don't see any exception thrown and i checked with the debugger that the code is executed only when the message box is shown.

I also tried to use *InputBindings* instead of *Interaction.Triggers*:

```
<ContentControl.InputBindings>
<MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
    Command="{Binding DataContext.HandleDoubleClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
```

But i see the same behavior. Enabling the *TraceLevel=High* didn't give me useful info..
Also, i tried to handle the right click event instead of the double click, but still, the command gets executed only sometimes.

I think i'm missing something here, could someone help me to understand what the issue is? or at least give me some advice on how i can debug the problem..
Thank you

**UPDATE**
I found out that the command gets always executed if i double click on the element text. The thing is that i would like it to be executed even if i double click on an empty space of the selected row of the ListView...

Comment: Where are you double-clicking when it doesn't work? Try to set the `Background` of the `WrapPanel` to `Transparent`. Then the command should be invoked whenever you click inside the `WrapPanel`.

Comment: I tried to set the background to transparent but it didn't  change anything. But setting it to yellow made me notice a thing: the double click works when i do it on the text of the list element. What i would like to achieve is to handle the double click on the entire row of the selected item... i tried to put the InputBindings on the ListView instead but i have the opposite behavior: the command is executed only when i click outside the selected elements, ie on the empty space of the list

Comment: Obviously, the command won't get invoked when you click anywhere outside the `WrapPanel`.

Comment: of course, the point is that the ListView Item is basically a row.. i expected the WrapPanel to extend for the entire row width but it doesn't, i want my command to get invoked when i double click anywhere on the item, i didn't find a way to bind the command to the ListView item, nor to make the WrapPanel fill the entire row.. Actually i'm trying different things, using different controls instead of the WrapPanel, but so far i didn't find a way to solve my problem. It seems that binding a command to a ListView item is not so straightforward as i initially thought..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `Margin` from the `WrapPanel` to the `TextBlock` and define an `ItemContainerStyle` that makes the contents of the `ListViewItem` stretch horizontally.

You should also set the `Background` property of the `WrapPanel` to capture the clicks:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.listElement}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding DataContext.HandleDoubleClickCommand, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <WrapPanel Background="Transparent">
                    <TextBlock Text="Data: " Margin="12"><Run FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding data}"/></TextBlock>
                </WrapPanel>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: That's awesome! this is just what i needed! thank you very much :)
Just a thing, it's not clear to me why the Background property has anything to do to capture the event...i mean, doesn't a control has a default background?

Comment: @giocarmine: No, if you don't set the `Background`, the area is considered to belong to the window itself and then there are no mouse events raised.